# Consolidate List of Similar Data into Single Row in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that lists donations given by constituents with a unique account number. Several constituents have made more than one donation in a given period of time listed separately. I would like to filter the list of constituents and include each of their gifts in the same row as their account information.

In the attached spreadsheet, Sheet1 shows a sample of the data, and the second sheet shows the desired results as I would like them displayed. I imagine some sort of array formula filter could accomplish this, but I'm at a loss how to construct it. Any help would be appreciated.

I created an example file with expected outcome: **[Consolidate List of Similar Data into Single Row](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dS4R-hcna5rC-Rnupg3ormN52wvsoEviJDXegJnr6k/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Very helpful to add the example file Jason. Welcome to Web Applications !!

Answer (score 1):

If prepared to add a helper column in `Sheet1` (say E, with `=countif(B$2:B2,B2)` in E2 copied down to suit), in C2 of `Desired Results` please try:

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!$D:$D,Sheet1!$B:$B,$B2,Sheet1!$E:$E,right(C$1,1))
```

and copy down and across to suit.

**Alternatively**, add a label (say `Gift#`) in Sheet1 E1 (with helper column as above) and create a pivot table with `Account#` and `Name` for Rows (uncheck Show totals), `Gift#` for Columns and `Gift` in Values.